# How to set environment variable for a deployed Reactjs app on server?

Tags: reactjs, server, build, environment-variables

I think my question is different from previously asked questions about environment variables. I know how to set the environment variables while building the ReactJs app. Once the app is built, it gives me the static files and i put it on server. This app works like a normal webapp. 
**Question:** 
If i want to give the client provision of changing one of the environment variables on a deployed build on server without opening the code files, how i can do that? 
**Note:**
As this is not a specific coding question, please move this question to relevant SO forum if you think.
Thanks

Comment: Just to confirm. You want to change an environment variable of the app that is already compiled and is being served from a webserver?

Comment: Yes. exactly ....

Comment: It is not possible to change `REACT_APP_XXXXX` env. vars after compilation. They are getting "baked in" into the app permanently. I solved this problem by having a dynamic JSON manifest file that is being served from the backend. The app loads the JSON file and reads its values. A variation of this approach is to have a Javascript `js` file served from the backend. The script executes a function which sets some variables in global `window`  object. I can give you some code example as an answer if you wish.

Comment: Yes please that would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to change REACT_APP_XXXXX env. vars after compilation. They are getting "baked in" into the app permanently.

I solved this problem by having a dynamic JSON manifest file that is being served from the backend. The app loads the JSON file and reads its values. A variation of this approach is to have a Javascript js file served from the backend. The script executes a function which sets some variables in global window object.

Here is a snippet of a node `express` app that serves the manifest as JSON and as a JS file.

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const manifest = {
    appTheme: process.env.APP_THEME,
    foo: "bar"
};

const cacheTimeoutSec = 600

class ManifestController {
    static getJS(req, res) {
        /// Generate IIFE function that sets window.serverManifest object
        let fileChunks = [
            '(function(){',
            'var serverManifest=',
            JSON.stringify(manifest),
            '; window.serverManifest = serverManifest',
            '})()',
        ].join('');

        res.set('Cache-Control', `public, max-age=${cacheTimeoutSec}`);
        res.setHeader('content-type', 'text/javascript');
        res.write(fileChunks);
        res.end();
    }

    static getJSON(req, res) {
        res.json(manifest);
    }
}

// Serve manifest in JS
app.get('/server-manifest.js', ManifestController.getJS);

// Serve manifest as JSON
app.get('/server-manifest.json', ManifestController.getJSON);
```

Option 1:

The react app manually fetches the JSON file from your backend (e.g. `https://api.mybackend.com/server-manifest.json`) and act on the data.

Option 2:

Include `<script>` tag in the html file header like so

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="https://api.mybackend.com/server-manifest.js"></script>
        <title>Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <noscript>
            You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
        </noscript>
        <div id="root"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

If you put it in the `<head>` the browser will load the script and will execute it. The script sets the manifest in the global `window.serverManifest` object which the React app can access now at any time.